# Sync my outlook (2007) calendar with hotmail calendar

Tags: sync, microsoft-outlook-2007, hotmail

I would think this should be simple ... I'm trying to figure out how to publish my outlook 2007 calendar from my desktop to my hotmail\live account.

I found a couple links (e.g. publish calendar, outlook connector) but they either don't seem to do what I want or don't work (maybe I'm missing some config step).

Mainly I just want to view my outlook calendar at my home or other computers.

So far google calendar sync ([link](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=89955)) but I don't really use my gmail account much and would rather push that info into hotmail or live account.

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the new [Outlook Social Connector](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9A2279B1-DF0A-46E1-AA93-7D4870871ECF&displaylang=en) [will fix this for you](http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/microsoft_makes_calendar_sync_work.php) according to ReadWriteWeb.com

> The previous version of this connector allowed you to sync email and contacts data between Outlook and Hotmail for free, but calendar sync required a subscription service. With this new version, however, calendar sync is now free and it includes the ability to work with Live Calendar beta. And because Live Calendar also supports calendar sharing, those shared calendars will sync back to Outlook, too.
>
> For someone who uses an Outlook calendar at work, keeps a personal calendar in Hotmail, and perhaps has a shared family calendar in Live Calendar, this new sync tool will be incredibly useful. Whether you're online or offline, all your calendars are available from one place: Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Outlook Connector will provide this functionality as suggested, but, Ivo, if you read the "Note" regarding the [Outlook Connector](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-a-windows-live-hotmail-account-in-outlook-HA010221823.aspx#BM7) it says:

> Note   You can view and edit your
>   Windows Live Calendar in Outlook,
>   however, your Outlook calendar will
>   not be available on Windows Live.

Basically this seems to provide an way to view\edit your online calendar in Outlook only.